# Can I merge archived maildir "inbox" and "sent" folders to get a usable threaded folder with both?

Tags: email, thunderbird, maildir

Apologies if this is a bit vague but I have two large files from an ancient email backup, that has a "email" file with all the emails as a giant text file, and then a "sent" file with all the outgoing emails I've sent.  By simply dragging and dropping them into a folder in my Thunderbird client, I've been able to (as if by magic!) see them all sort into nice individual emails that I can filter through by subject, sender, recipient, and so on, but to see my replies I have to switch to a different folder and hunt for the reply over there.

Is there a method to combine these two separate files such that an email thread's info will be present and I can see what was replied to and from?

Thank you for any thoughts.  I suspect that if I were to simply merge the two files I'd be able to have it sortable by date, but I'd love to have it even more linked if possible.

Again, thank you!

(I'm running Lubuntu 20.04LTS, if it matters, and Thunderbird 78.)

Comment: [This](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/message-threading-thunderbird) wouldn't do the trick for you?

Answer (score 0):

> I have two large files from an ancient email backup, that has a "email" file with all the emails as a giant text file, and then a "sent" file with all the outgoing emails I've sent. By simply dragging and dropping them into a folder in my Thunderbird client, I've been able to

This sounds like a *mbox* mail folder traditional in Unix mail systems. It was actually also the storage format used by Thunderbird until a few versions ago.

> Is there a method to combine these two separate files such that an email thread's info will be present and I can see what was replied to and from?

Drag and drop all your messages into a single folder within Thunderbird. Thread information is stored as part of the message's internal metadata – most mail clients thread messages according to their `Message-Id:`, `References:`, and `In-Reply-To:` headers; those are preserved when moving the message around.

(In some cases, often with IMAP folders, Thunderbird might refuse to thread a conversation because it has bad information cached in its "summary" files (Inbox.msf, etc) – using "Repair" would fix that.)

It should also be possible to just concatenate the two mbox files together, as they're already just a series of messages (each prefixed with a `From abc@def` header as the delimiter).

Comment: thank you, I really appreciate this comment.  I have tried the above and seem to just get a big blank nothing when I try combining the files.  If I leave them untouched, I can drag them into my "Local" directory and access them separately.  If I put them together or into a folder and drag...it doesn't work.  Tbird opens, but when I click on the folder (or file) I see nothing.

Comment: I've also found a file called "Smail" that has a totally different system:  each email is its own text file.  Can I somehow bring this into Thunderbird as well?

Comment: Don't combine the originals then, load them both separately into Thunderbird and use it to copy all _messages_ into a Thunderbird folder. Are the files in "Smail" named after simple numbers or is the naming more complex, and/or is there a `.mh_sequences` file in that directory?

Comment: The are all simple numbers, like 103, 104, 105, etc.

Comment: Sounds like an MH folder. You can rename the files adding the `.eml` extension, then drag all files into Thunderbird to import. (Alternatively, Mutt can be used to open MH folders and copy their contents into another folder type like Maildir or IMAP.)

Comment: Hmmm, I renamed 501 to 501.eml, but didn't seem to get anywhere...I didn't drag them into the top level folder though, just dragged their folder "Inbox" into the Local folder in Thunderbird.  It didn't work.  It shows the folder and the files (listed as folders, 501.eml) but nothing inside.

Comment: Drag the _individual files_ into one of Thunderbird's folders, not the directory.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work either.  Same thing:  I can see the file in the pane on the left, but when I click, it's just white space.  Nothing readable.  

I also found (this has been quite an adventure in email formats), a folder with three folders inside, "cur," "tmp" and "new" and inside the "cur" folder, there are files with a longer name, such as "1143810431.8108.XOXE4:2,RS".  These I haven't done anything with either, yet, but would love to know if they're usable within Thunderbird too.

But the one with 103, 104, etc. has hundreds of emails, would be nice to read them.